# Render animation don’t start first frame

Tags: rendering, keyframes

I try to render my animation but since 1 day the render automatically start at frame 1528 for no reason. When i try to render single keyframe it works perfectly fine but "Render animation" doesn't want to work from frame 0 to 1527.
When i tryed to set the animation range from 0 to 1500 blender didn't even launch no render.

I leave the .blend here if someone can spot the issue it would help me a lot !
Thanks in advance !

https://app.box.com/s/iix6xm6a8fyh3t74em2b1t38cyepua4y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have disabled *Image Sequence* > *Overwrite* in the *Output Properties*, so I would guess you have already rendered frames 0 to 1527 and did not delete them before starting a new render. Good idea if you started rendering, had to pause and want to resume rendering later. Bad idea if you want to start again from the beginning. Since I do not have your drive in my computer I cannot check if the files are there, at least I can say it started rendering at frame 0 for me.

[image: overwrite option]